# Windows 10 won't shut down - I run out of solutions :(

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

My computer won't shut down. If you try to shut down the LED on the Power button will continue to be on and you can clearly hear all the fans inside running. It's stuck in Limbo. Only after pressing the power button for a view seconds it properly shuts down.

I've spent weeks looking for a solution, now I'm just really disappointed by Windows and myself for not getting this fixed. I really hope you guys can help me.

This is my system:

```
Intel Core i5 2500k CPU
Asus P8P67 Rev 3. Mainboard
Kingston 16GB HyperX DDR3 RAM
Samsung 850 Evo 500GB SSD
2nd 500GB hard disk
Corsair 500W CM9 PSU
```

This is what I've tried so far:

- Disabled the Windows 10 hibernate / fast startup feature
- Tried to downgrade the Intel Management Engine drivers to a 9.xx Version
- Tried multiple versions of Intel Rapid Storage (now uninstalled it)
- Tried multiple Intel Chipset drivers
- Tried to disable every non-windows service to see if it's a software issue.
- Replaced PSU

I tried to find a solution with Windows and Asus but both keep saying this is not a common issue.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: First try this: Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator and type `shutdown /s /f`  -  Does this make any difference?

Comment: What do you mean by that? - oh, now I get it. Duplicate of that other post :)
Thanks for the link. I'll go through that and see what those solutions do.
As for the Windows licence itself, I'm using the same licence for my PC and my Ultrabook but as far as I know that shouldn't be an issue.
It's Windows 10 Education which I'm entiteled to through university.